# Cgminer not working with AMD APP SDK 2.8

Tags: miner-configuration, cgminer

Before I install AMD APP SDK 2.8, I get this error from cgminer 3.7.2:

> [2014-01-06 22:44:56] Error -1001: clGetPlatformsIDs failed (no OpenCL SDK installed?)
>   [2014-01-06 22:44:56] clDevicesNum returned error, no GPUs usable
>   [2014-01-06 22:44:58] No devices detected!

After I install APP SDK 2.8, I get this window:

> cgminer.exe has stopped working

My graphics card is ATI Radeon HD 545v. I have tried both Catalyst 13.4 and 12.10. The software versions are all 64 bit (except miners).

After installing SDK 2.8, guiminer exits when I run it. Before installation it shows a window:

> No OpenCL devices were found.
>   If you only want to mine using CPU or CUDA, you can ignore this message.
>   If you want to mine on ATI graphics cards, you may need to install the ATI Stream SDK, or your GPU may not support OpenCL.

Question: How do I get to mining?

Comment: i had same problem and installed sdk and problem solved...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using windows:

uninstall all AMD drivers

Do not install (uninstall) APP SDK.

download 3.11 beta version of catalyst drivers
http://www.guru3d.com/files_get/amd_catalyst_13_11_beta_9_2_(13_250_18_november_7)_download,1.html

Make sure you're cgminer settings are modeset and try again. If you are never on modest cgminer settings, you may never know if your software/driver config will work.

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux you will need to install:

- AMD Drivers
- AMD SDK
- AMD ADL

I suggest using the following link as a guide, it has all the steps in detail.

[Configure CGMiner 3.7.2 Under Linux](https://coinaxis.com/index.php/news/entry/how-to-configure-linux-and-build-cgminer-for-bitcoin-and-litecoin)

If you are using windows then you should be able to run it straight off.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in the command line if you haven't already.

```
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the SDK.  I don't think that it's necessary anymore.

Try uninstalling ALL AMD drivers (SDK and GPU), then reinstall just the Catalyst drivers.  See if that helps.

Comment: It is still necessary for scyrpt on GPU's